# PHP - Finding consecutive day counts in an array

Tags: php

Let's say I have an array called $selectedDates containing the following

```
$selectedDates = [
    "2000-01-31",
    "2000-02-01",
    "2000-02-02",
    "2000-02-20"
];
```

Is there some way in PHP to calculate out what # each day is consecutively.

So that the first one returns 1, the 2nd one would be returning 2, the 3rd would be 3 but the 4th would be 1 again.

I'm trying to loop through them all at the moment but am not really getitng anywhere.

```
<?php foreach ($selectedDates as $date): ?>
    Seriously lost about what to put here.
    <?php echo $consecDayCount; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm thinking inside of the loop I may need to loop through it again? And start at the first one and check each day going up one more, adding to some incrementer for each day that says the previous date in the array was the previous day in time. I'm just kind of banging my head against a wall figuring out that part.

Comment: What do you mean by ***finding consecutive day counts for each day in an array***? How many times **`2000-01-31`** _(for example)_ exists in the array or that from **`2000-01-31`** until **`2000-02-02`** it's 3 consecutive days?

Comment: @AngelPolitis the 2nd one. In a foreach loop I'd like to echo 3 for the 2000-02-02 date. Sorry!

Comment: Okay @Octoxan, I changed the title to make it more understandable.

Comment: @AngelPolitis Thank you. I know I'll have so somehow start from my current day and work backwards, I think?

Comment: Just for make it clear for all: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104624

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Yep that's exactly what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to Rome...

```
# We assume $selectedDates is sorted at this point.
$selectedDates = [
    "2000-01-31",
    "2000-02-01",
    "2000-02-02",
    "2000-02-20"
];

# The array we will print.
$coll = array();

# We use array_reverse to start from the last entry.
foreach(array_reverse($selectedDates) as $date) {
   $tmp = $date; 
   $con = 1;
   do $tmp = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$tmp -1day"));
   # ++$con is used to count only up if in_array gives true.
   while(in_array($tmp, $selectedDates) && (++$con));
   $coll[$date] = $con;
}

print_r($coll);
```

Result: `Array ( [2000-02-20] => 1 [2000-02-02] => 3 [2000-02-01] => 2 [2000-01-31] => 1 )`

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Makes perfect sense after going through it.

Comment: Excellent and succinct answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$selectedDates = [
    '2000-01-31',
    '2000-02-01',
    '2000-02-02',
    '2000-02-20',
    '2000-02-21',
];

$format = 'Y-m-d';
$consecutive = [];

$length = count($selectedDates);
$streak = false;
$last = null;

for($index = 0; $index < $length - 1; $index++) {
    $firstDate = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $selectedDates[$index]);
    $secondDate = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $selectedDates[$index + 1]);

    $diff = $firstDate->diff($secondDate);

    if ($diff->days === 1) {
        // consecutive dates
        if ($streak) {
            $consecutive[$last]++; // we have another consecutive day to the current streak
        } else {
            $consecutive[$selectedDates[$index]] = 2; // we already have 2 consecutive days
            $last = $selectedDates[$index];
            $streak = true;
        }
    } else {
        $streak = false;
    }
}


var_dump($consecutive);
```

This will give you an array in the `date => number of consecutive days starting on that date` format.

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
$dates = array(
    new DateTime('2000-01-31'), 
    new DateTime('2000-02-01'), 
    new DateTime('2000-02-02'), 
    new DateTime('2000-02-20'), 

);

// process the array

$lastDate = null;
$ranges = array();
$currentRange = array();

foreach ($dates as $date) {    

    if (null === $lastDate) {
        $currentRange[] = $date;
    } else {

        // get the DateInterval object
        $interval = $date->diff($lastDate);

        // DateInterval has properties for 
        // days, weeks. months etc. You should 
        // implement some more robust conditions here to 
        // make sure all you're not getting false matches
        // for diffs like a month and a day, a year and 
        // a day and so on...

        if ($interval->days === 1) {
            // add this date to the current range
            $currentRange[] = $date;    
        } else {
            // store the old range and start anew
            $ranges[] = $currentRange;
            $currentRange = array($date);
        }
    }

    // end of iteration... 
    // this date is now the last date     
    $lastDate = $date;
}

// messy... 
$ranges[] = $currentRange;

// print dates

foreach ($ranges as $range) {

    // there'll always be one array element, so 
    // shift that off and create a string from the date object 
    $startDate = array_shift($range);
    $str = sprintf('%s', $startDate->format('D j M'));

    // if there are still elements in $range
    // then this is a range. pop off the last 
    // element, do the same as above and concatenate
    if (count($range)) {
        $endDate = array_pop($range);
        $str .= sprintf(' to %s', $endDate->format('D j M'));
    }

    echo "<p>$str</p>";
}  ?>
```

output::: Mon 31 Jan to Wed 2 Feb

Sun 20 Feb

Comment: This doesn't return what the OP requests.